# Email with nonexistent domain name fails regex validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have the following validation on my user model:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email,
    presence: true,
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

It works fine for emails except 1 email. I need this email to be valid. The test that fails is the following:

```
  it 'should accept a domain with more than 4 letters', focus: true do
    user.email = 'ecample@yahoo.today'
    expect(user.valid?).to be(true)
  end
```

This test should pass. Any ideas?(I am open to changing the regex completely for email validation)

These are all the validators on the User model on the email field:

```
#<EmailValidator:0x000000075b04d0
  @attributes=[:email],
  @options={:if=>#<Proc:0x000000075c5a10@/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@2parale/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.37/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb:30>}>,
 #<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x00000007414338 @attributes=[:email], @options={}>,
 #<ActiveModel::Validations::FormatValidator:0x0000000740ef28 @attributes=[:email], @options={:with=>/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i}>,
 #<ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator:0x0000000740de98 @attributes=[:email], @options={:minimum=>6, :maximum=>100}>,
 #<ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator:0x0000000740ccf0
```

Comment: Can you pry open the test and see what errors are on the user? (just double confirm the email validator is what is failing)

Comment: Yes , I did that, it's the email. I checked all validations on the user model also and it's the right expression .. ( User.validations_on(:email) ). I also have 5 others tests with emails that pass

Comment: This is what i get with pry in the test @messages={:email=>["This field is not an email."]}

Comment: Also i've tried to match this email with the expression in IRB and it does return a match

Comment: Yeah - your regex looks fine to me. I know Devise has some "out of the box" validation. Could you overwrite the devise email regex in the initializer (config.email_regexp = /PATTERN/)?

Comment: I did but the test still fails must I replace the validation somewhere ? (in the model somehow ? )

Comment: Your regex doesn't accept capital letters in the domain. I'd say if it doesn't work with `ecample@yahoo.today` then the email is either altered with caps or it has other characters in it. Do test cases, like `.*?@.*` then narrow it down by adding parts of your regex.

Comment: well if I write ecample@yahoo.com it works... If i write example@today.com it works there is something with today at the end that makes user validation fail. I do use devise and devide_token_auth for authentication but I don't see how that could impact the validation

Comment: This might have to do with a current issue/PR on devise and their existing email validation (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/4001/files). My main suggestion would be updating the regex in the devise initializer and restart your server. To replace the validation as you asked I would try something like: `validates_format_of :email, with: Devise.email_regexp`

Comment: I did that , it still fails i don't get it. Why would it validate the email domain , is this a setting in the devise gem or something ?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb => `Automatically validate if the email is present, unique and its format is valid. Also tests presence of password, confirmation and length.`

Comment: So the answer would be no since I provided the regexp with your help ...

Comment: I just realized I was ignoring devise_token_auth. If you look at the validators present, it is running through the EmailValidator on that gem first (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/validators/email_validator.rb). I notice that the error message you are seeing is coming from their locale so that is the validator that must be failing. I haven't used devise_token_auth, but removing/overriding that validator should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: How do i override this ? :)) :D

Comment: Looks like other folks have the same issue with that gem (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/314) Fining another gem (not ideal Im sure), monkey patching the gem (also not ideal), or forking the gem (still not idea) seem to be the best options. Moving this to a new Answer to stop the long comment thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue where the `devise_auth_token` gem is overriding the default Devise email validations (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/314) causing issues for some folks. Unfortunately it does not appear that there is a nice way to tell the gem which updated format/validator you would like to use. This leaves you with three non-ideal options:

1. Find another gem with less obtrusive behavior
2. Monkey patch the class in question (EmailValidator)
3. Fork the gem with the updates/changes you need and submit a PR

Sorry there doesn't seem to be a nice/easy way to fix this :(

Cheers.

Comment: Lol you really did find the problem ... it would have taken me so much time.. Thank you very much for all your help and your time spent on my question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [python-email-validator](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator) ?

**Install**:

```
pip install email_validator
```

**Sample usage**:

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError

email = "my+address@mydomain.tld"

try:
    v = validate_email(email) # validate and get info
    email = v["email"] # replace with normalized form
except EmailNotValidError as e:
    # email is not valid, exception message is human-readable
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: I need to do this on a live app, I'd rather not install more things for a validation ...